# Invalid move condition, Python text based game

Tags: python

I need help with a text-based python game, I have done most of the work, I can move between all 3 rooms, there is 'Great hall' at the top then go south 'Bedroom' go east 'Cellar' the I can go back so go west 'bedroom' go north finally to get back to the great hall.

the problem is if I'm in the great hall and type east it skips to cellar instead of saying invalid move there's a wall.
what I'm trying to do

> > Output that displays the room the player is currently in.
> > Decision branching that tells the game how to handle the different commands. The commands can be to either move between rooms (such as go North, South, East, or West) or exit.
> > If the player enters a valid “move” command, the game should use the dictionary to move them into the new room.
> > If the player enters “exit,” the game should set their room to a room called “exit.”
> > If the player enters an invalid command, the game should output an error message to the player (input validation).
> > A way to end the gameplay loop once the player is in the “exit” room

this is the code I have written so far

```
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}


def player_stat():
    print("-" * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(currentRoom))
    print("-" * 20)


currentRoom = 'Great Hall'
player_move = ''

while currentRoom != 'Exit':
    player_stat()
    player_move = input('Enter your move:\n')
    if player_move in ['Exit', 'exit']:
        currentRoom = 'Exit'
        print('Play again soon')
    elif player_move in ['South', "south"]:
        currentRoom = 'Bedroom'
    elif player_move in ['North', "north"]:
        currentRoom = 'Great Hall'
        print("You made it back to the Great Hall")
    elif player_move in ['East', 'east']:
        currentRoom = 'Cellar'
        print('YOU MADE IT TO THE CELLAR, try to go back to the Great Hall')
    elif player_move in ['West', "west"]:
        currentRoom = 'Bedroom'
print("You made it back to the Bedroom")
```

Please help me

Comment: "if I'm in the great hall", then check currentRoom too

Comment: You're not using your dictionary at all! If the player is currently in `"Great Hall"`, then their only available moves are the keys in the associated dictionary. Consider using something like `legal_moves = rooms[current_room]`.

Comment: PS - as a small optimization, use `player_move.lower() == "north"` etc. That way, any whacky spelling of `"nOrTH"` is acceptable.

Comment: Where and how do I add The legal moves, I am so new to this it’s like an new language. This is for a class and I don’t want to fail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'south': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'north': 'Great Hall', 'east': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'west': 'Bedroom'}
}


def player_stat():
    print("-" * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(currentRoom))
    print("-" * 20)


currentRoom = 'Great Hall'
player_move = ''

while currentRoom != 'Exit':
    player_stat()
    player_move = input('Enter your move:\n').lower()
    if player_move in ['Exit', 'exit']:
        currentRoom = 'Exit'
        print('Play again soon')
        continue

    try:
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][player_move]
    except Exception:
        print("invalid move")
        continue


    if currentRoom == 'Great Hall':
        print("You made it back to the Great Hall")
    elif currentRoom == 'Cellar':
        print('YOU MADE IT TO THE CELLAR, try to go back to the Great Hall')

print("You made it back to the Bedroom")
```

Comment: I tweaked your dictionary so it accepts all inputs by lowering them.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to utilize the dictionary. It involves nested conditional statements.

```
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}


def player_stat():
    print("-" * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(currentRoom))
    print("-" * 20)


currentRoom = 'Great Hall'
player_move = ''

while currentRoom != 'Exit':
    player_stat()
    player_move = input('Enter your move:\n').title()
    if player_move == 'Exit':
        currentRoom = 'Exit'
    else:
        if player_move in rooms[currentRoom]:
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][player_move]
            if currentRoom == 'Great Hall':
                print("You made it back to the Great Hall")
            elif currentRoom == 'Cellar':
                print('YOU MADE IT TO THE CELLAR, try to go back to the Great Hall')
        else:
            print("That is not a valid move, try again.")

print('Play again soon')
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. I just can’t do South I have to do south. I can fix this though. Thank you, you are a life saver. I would literally pay for that help. God bless you, I hope you get the best job ever